# Seaborn : cut display

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm doing violin plots, but I have extreme data points, therefore I get something like that :

```
sns.violinplot(x = "x_axis", y = "y_axis", hue="groups", data = my_data, split = True)
```

[image: with extremes]

If I cut the data on the Y axis to exclude > 200 however, like this :

```
cut_data = my_data[my_data.y_axis < 200]
sns.violinplot(x = "x_axis", y = "y_axis", hue="groups", data = cut_data, split = True)
```

I get something like this :

[image: with data cut]

But of course, this is undesired because this second plot is not the same as the first one as far as the underlying data goes.
So my question is : is there a way to graph all the data but have the graph show only from 0 to 200 on the Y axis ?

Comment: Does this do what you need? `ax.set_ylim(0, 200)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can truncate the plot itself by setting the y axis limit on the matplotlib axis object:

```
#create a sample data set
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.gamma(1, 100, 10000), columns=['a'])
df['Group'] = np.random.choice(['group 1', 'group 2'], 10000)

#plot and the truncate the axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
sns.violinplot(x='Group', y='a', data=df, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(0, 200)
```

[image]